# ASP.NET MVC query deployed Application Server Address while not in request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, httpcontext

This question looks like [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916092/asp-net-mvc-deployed-application-server-address) doesn't it? Slight difference. I want to know the deployed address of the server while I am doing initial setup (in Application start) and at that time there is no request:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

So I cannot query it to get the current URL. Is there another way?

Comment: Two things that I'm curious of...what do you need this for (might be a better way?) and what version of the mvc framework are you using?

Comment: I'm doing a dodgy hack for development where I am locating wcf services in code and know the relative path to the service, from the current url. MVC 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [HostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx) class. You might also take a look at the [following article](http://weblogs.asp.net/reganschroder/archive/2008/07/25/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-application-start.aspx) if the information you need is not present in the `HostingEnvironment` class. In this article the author performs the initialization logic in the `Application_BeginRequest` method instead of `Application_Start`. It uses a lock to ensure that this initialization is performed only once:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = app.Context;

    // Attempt to peform first request initialization

    FirstRequestInitialization.Initialize(context);
}
```

and here's the `FirstRequestInitialization` class:

```
class FirstRequestInitialization
{
    private static bool s_InitializedAlready = false;
    private static Object s_lock = new Object();

    // Initialize only on the first request

    public static void Initialize(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (s_InitializedAlready)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (s_lock)
        {
            if (s_InitializedAlready)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Perform first-request initialization here ...

            s_InitializedAlready = true;
        }
    }
}
```